# What signals does Blender respond to?

Tags: linux

By "signals" I mean the age-old unix signals like SIGSTOP, SIGQUIT, SIGPWR, SIGALRM, SIGUSR1, etc.

Which ones does the Blender process not ignore, and how does it react to each?    I'm curious about signals sent to Blender by the operating system, user, or other software.

I don't recall seeing mention anywhere in any documentation.

Comment: curious to know, is there some signal you were looking to use that wasn't working as expected?

Comment: What would the advantages be of SIGTSTP over SIGSTOP? (which works)

Answer (score 9):

Here are the signals Blender currently uses.

- `SIGINT` (Ctrl+C in the terminal) is used to cancel renders.
- `SIGFPE` can be enabled by passing `--debug-fpe` to Blender, we use the for finding errors while debugging.
- `SIGSEGV` writes a crash log in the temp directory, unless `--disable-crash-handler` argument is passed.