# Abort script that renders frames

Tags: python, command-line

My script runs through a `for` loop, each time rendering a frame. How can I abort the script?

Normally, I'd use <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal Blender was launched from, but this doesn't work.  It just waits until the current frame is done and then raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in some file called `.../2.69/scripts/addons/cycles/engine.py`, but continues on to the next frame.

Here is a simplified version of my script:

```
import bpy

framesToRender = (1, 3, 4, 6, 7)

for frame in framesToRender:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/home/garrett/Desktop/" + str(frame).zfill(4)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

**EDIT:**

The only way I've figured out to stop it is by killing Blender from the System Monitor (for Ubuntu), or close the terminal Blender was launched from. Using [`xkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkill) on Blender kills the user interface, but doesn't stop the script.

Comment: I am not sure in what part of the script you want to abort, but you can try `raise`ing and `Exception` manually in your code.

Comment: The tiny `x` button in the info header during a rendering process is hardcoded, it's unfortunately not an operator you could call from python :(

Comment: @Vader, thanks, but I'm trying to stop the script running using a command entered into the terminal Blender was called from (since the script can take many hours to finish), not from a command coded into the script.

Comment: The reason why `Ctrl+C` doesn't work is because it sends `SIGINT`, [which is used to stop renders](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1800/599) (hence the cycles reference). If you don't mind killing blender too, either `killall blender` or `kill $(pgrep blender)` should stop the script as well.

Comment: Couldn't you add a simple `if stop` to your render loop and set it to true on `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: The exception does not reach the executing for loop. It is consumed before and not raised again. Seems like the render operator always returns 'FINISHED'. So you can not check for that, neither.

Comment: I wonder where it's consumed, looks like a bug or misconcepted operator if it's impossible to catch.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, good point.  I [can't](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6879/redirect-output-of-bpy-ops-render-render-to-variable) even seem to intercept the console output by changing `sys.stdout`.  If I could, then I could search through it for `KeyboardInterrupt` before printing it to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop the loop you can install your own handler for the SIGINT signal which is executed by the main thread. (see [signal module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html))

The rendering of the current frame will not abort.

```
import bpy
import signal

abort = None

def hndl(signum, frame):
    global abort
    abort = True
    print("\nAbort")
    #uncomment to call the default handler
    #raising the KeyboardInterruption exception
    #signal.default_int_handler(signum, frame)

def run():
    global abort
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, hndl)
    count = 0
    abort = False
    while not abort and count < 10:
        count += 1
        print(count, abort)
        bpy.ops.render.render()

def reset():   
    signal.signal(
        signal.SIGINT, 
        signal.default_int_handler
        )

if __name__== "__main__":
    run()
    reset()
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a bit? How does this stop the render mid-frame?

Comment: That seems to work.  I've tested it on Linux and Windows.