# Redirect output of bpy.ops.render.render() to variable

Tags: python

I thought that the following code (which I found [here](http://wrongsideofmemphis.com/2010/03/01/store-standard-output-on-a-variable-in-python/)) would save all the terminal output from the function `bpy.ops.render.render()` into the variable `output`:

```
import bpy, sys, io

old_stdout = sys.stdout
render_output = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = render_output
bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

But I still get output to the terminal (`Saved: /tmp/a.png Time: 00:00.99 (Saving: 00:00.01)`) and `render_output.getvalue()` returns an empty string.  Why is that?

I also tested this method with `bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()` and it successfully redirects the output.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I am facing it also. Could you share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have worked, if the `bpy.ops.render.render()` operator was outputting that information through Python. However, since that code is written in C (`blender\source\blender\editors\render\render_internal.c`), it doesn't care that you've reassigned `sys.out` in Python.

Comment: Could you please let me know if there is any solution to the problem?