# How to write the output of Blender console out to a file

Tags: python, command-line

Is it possible to launch Blender in a mode where everything that appears in the Blender Console is sent to a file?

Comment: That's OK, mods can add the tags that are necessary to your question later. Creating new tags is generally not a good idea, because it makes organization more difficult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux/Ubuntu its `./blender > myLog123.txt` from the working directory.

`./blender &> myLog123.txt` to include Stderr.

In Python you can do

```
import sys
file = open(filepath, "w")
sys.stdout = file
#...
#...
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ #reset
file.close()
```

to catch the console output while your script is running.

Comment: Changing sys.stdout in Python apparently catches most of the console output, but [not everything](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6879/redirect-output-of-bpy-ops-render-render-to-variable).

Comment: Oh that's a very cool / useful approach... will definitively try that!

Answer (score 6):

On Windows,

1. Open a command prompt (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Drag the Blender shortcut or exe onto the prompt
   `C:\Users\Yourname>C:\Path\to\Blender.exe`
3. Add `> %homepath%\Desktop\blender.log`
4. Hit return to start Blender with all console output redirected to `blender.log` on your Desktop.

For Mac and Linux, have a look here:

http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/window_system/console_window.html

Comment: Thanks CoDEmanX... didn't think of that one, will try too!