# Suppress console output during render

Tags: command-line

I render an animation using a Python script inside of the Blender 2.82a text editor:

```
import bpy
import os
import sys

import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()

bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

b = datetime.datetime.now()

print(f"Render Time: {b-a}")
print()
```

The console outputs information for every frame:

```
Append frame 0
    Time: 00:00.09 (Saving: 00:00.00)
Append frame 1
    Time: 00:00.07 (Saving: 00:00.02)
...
Append frame 60
    Time: 00:00.04 (Saving: 00:00.00)

Render Time: 0:00:03.429938
```

I'd like to suppress the "Append frame...." lines (but not suppress any other console messages like print(), etc.).

This question has been asked a lot and I have tried all the various answers but all attempts at suppressing the Blender console's stdout have not been able to suppress this (Render Frame info) part of the output (although I can suppress other things like print() statements. etc.).

Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, should all output of `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)` not appear on stdout or just the "Append frame" line?

Comment: I would like to suppress all the frame line reports (it does one for every frame): "Append frame 1 Time: 00:00.07 (Saving: 00:00.02)" but I'd keep things like print().

Comment: This would most likely require to start Blender from command line to redirect stdout for the executable, since the part that prints these statements is in Blender's C code and not part of a Python script. Changing stdout for the Python interpreter won't affect it, as explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6879/redirect-output-of-bpy-ops-render-render-to-%20variable). If you could tell us why you don't want these lines in the output perhaps we there are other solutions as well.

Comment: For the the test code I placed above it is not a  problem since I only have print() at the end of the run. But if I have a case where I want to print some diagnostics to the console prior to the render, then render, then print more diagnostics post-render, it would be a problem for a larger render since I will have thousands of lines of "Append frame...." in between my other print statements. I think what I might do is print my diagnostics to a file and use that so that whatever else goes to the console will not matter.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution.